# Problemas con URLs amigables

Tags: php, .htaccess

En el código desde PHP, en los enlaces estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
<h1><a href='noticias/" .  str_replace(" ","-",$articulos[$i]['titulo']) . "'>" . $articulos[$i]['titulo'] . "</a></h1>
```

El cual me origina una URL por ejemplo tal que así: http://www.miweb.com/private/noticias/Ya-se-conocen-los-Games-With-Gold-de-junio (el enlace no incluye mi dominio, no intentéis entrar porque no existe esa URL).

En htaccess para que entienda esa URL, debería coger el ID de ese enlace. Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^private/noticias/(.+)$ private/noticias.php?ID=$1
```

Pero me devuelve una página de error. No entiendo exactamente cómo funciona pero es lo que he visto en una web donde explican cómo usar URLs amigables. Lo que no entiendo es cómo voy a estar pasando el ID si sólo estoy pasando el título de la noticia. Estoy hecho un lío con este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sirva:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_origin=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ (/.*)?/index.(htm|html|php|asp)
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(htm|html|php|asp)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**PHP**

```
if(!isset($_GET['url_origin']) || $_GET['url_origin'] == '')
{
    $urlNueva = 'index';
}
else
{
    $_GET['url_origin'] = rawurlencode($_GET['url_origin']);
    $_GET['url_origin'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url_origin']);
    $pos = strrpos($_GET['url_origin'], "'");
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        $cadenaUrl = explode("%2F", $_GET['url_origin']);//%2F es este simbolo: /
        $urlNueva = $cadenaUrl[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $urlNueva = 'index';
    }
}
```

Con esto ya deberias poder hacer urls amigables, y la varibale `$cadenaUrl` es un array que contiene todos las rutas de la url, es decir, si tu url es: `/private/noticias/Ya-se-conocen-los-Games-With-Gold-de-junio`, tendria:

```
$cadenaUrl[0] => private
$cadenaUrl[1] => noticias
$cadenaUrl[2] => Ya-se-conocen-los-Games-With-Gold-de-junio
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Lo he probado y algo hace, pero me redirige a la misma página principal en vez de a la noticia y los estilos no se cargan. Lo cierto es que de momento el código me suena a Chino, ¿hay algún tutorial donde se explique de forma más extensa?

Comment: Te dirige a la pagina principal porque es desde ahi donde tienes que gestionarlo. Aqui te dejon un video-tutorial haber si te sirve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6w0sN_cQWQ @JetLagFox